# RIAK php client timeout error

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, riak

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Nginx 1.4.6 with php5-fpm.

I have a code with **RIAK php api** ( riak-pb ). When i run it in browser, it works well ( in this case FetchObject ).

I click the browser refresh button more time and my sample code runs well as expected: echoes the FetchedObject. But for examle i wait ( randomly ) few minutes and i want to run my code again, it fails with 504 Gateway time-out.

At this moment no one php code can run at my host.

*My NGINX log:*

> [error] 8491#0: *20 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /getContent.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "localhost"

I realized my php-fpm has some error but no log about it.
A **sudo service php5-fpm restart** command can solve it immediately ( or wait few minutes again ). But i can cause this error again anytime. Sometimes immediately, sometimes after a long trying.

Pls help me.

**Update:**

I've updated my NGINX to version 1.10.0 but nothing changed.

Comment: I have a very similar issue. I've opened this bug on Github: https://github.com/basho/riak-phppb-client/issues/12

Comment: Thank you. I had no change with php, so I've changed my backend to JAVA and JAVA wokrs perfectly.